# struck with for-each in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

This is my xml document.I want to convert this to another xml format using xslt2.0.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
        <w:body>

            <w:tbl/>
            <w:tbl/>
       </w:body>
      </w:document>
```

This is my xslt 2.0 code snippt.

```
<xsl:for-each select="following::node()[1]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::w:tbl and (parent::w:body)">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="self::w:tbl"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each> 


<xsl:template match="w:tbl">
    <table>
      table data
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

**My generated output is :**

```
<table>
     table data
   <table>
       table data
    </table>
 </table>
```

**But My required output is :**

```
<table>
     table data
</table>
<table>
     table data
</table>
```

Comment: Do you really have to use these "fore-each" function? This is quite ugly while selecting even "following::node" etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what the context item is at the point where your xsl:for-each gets executed. The fact that you don't give us this information may suggest that you haven't understood how important context is in XSLT. It's not possible to correct your code without knowing what the context is.

If your code were correct then the whole for-each could be simplified to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following::node()[1][self::w:tbl][parent::w:body]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to transform **w:tbl** elements that are child elements of **w:body** elements, you could just have a template match the body elements that then looks for the tbl elements

```
<xsl:template match="w:body">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="w:tbl"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The template matching **w:tbl** would be as before. Here is the full XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
   exclude-result-prefixes="w">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="w:body"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:body">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="w:tbl"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:tbl">
      <table> table data </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table> table data </table>
<table> table data </table>
```